# How to apply a discount for a specific user role in total cart but not for the shipping cost?

Tags: php, wordpress

We want to apply a 2% for only specific users with specific role, so we use this code in functions.php to solve that:

```
function tl_user_role_percent_discount( $cart ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $percent = $discount = 0;

  if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_meta = get_userdata( $user->ID );
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

    if ( in_array( 'cliente_vip', $user_roles, true ) ) {
      $percent = 2;
      $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percent / 100;
      $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Discount (2%)', -$discount);

    }
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'tl_user_role_percent_discount', 99, 1 );
```

How to exclude the Shipping cost to not discount anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$discount = ( $cart->get_subtotal() - $cart->get_shipping_total() ) * $percent / 100;
```